# Problem with copy-paste under Gnome session on 17.10

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, 17.10, clipboard

After upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 I have problem with copy-paste under Gnome session.

From Firefox (v 56.0) I copied table (382 rows, 15 cols) as HTML and I tried to paste to LibreOffice Calc (v5.4.1.2) under Gnome session on Ubuntu 17.10, but after about 1 minute is error "The contents of the clipbord could not be pasted".

When I login on Unity session I can copy table (382 rows, 15 cols) as HTML and I pasted to LibreOffice Calc without problem.

When I divide tables to less parts under Gnome Session I can copy part of table and I pasted to LibreOffice Calc without problem.

Why I can not copy and paste full table on Gnome session?